# Converting categorical variables in R for ANN (neuralnet)

Tags: r, neural-network

I have dataset which consists of credit details of customers. I have to build Neural Network model on this data set using the neuralnet library. This data set contains categorical variables. I need to transform these variables before running it. Can someone help me with this.

Variable in data set :

**checking_balance** :  < 0 DM,  1 - 200 DM,  unknown,  < 0 DM

**purpose**: furniture, education, cars

**employment_duration**: > 7 years,  1 - 4 years,  4 - 7 years

**credit_history**:   very good,  critical,  good

**months_loan_duration**:   6,   48,  12,  42

Thank you..

Comment: What do you mean by transformation? Please add a reproducible example.

Comment: @Ravi For example:
before transformation: employment_duration: > 7 years, 1 - 4 years, 4 - 7 years
After transformation:employment_duration:1.0,2.0,3.0

checking_balance should become 0,1,2,3

Basically its like transforming categorical variable into a numeric variable

Comment: Is the example in `?neuralnet` insufficient to infer how to use this function?

Comment: Yes, the example is in neural net and that is why I am not able to work with categorical variables...

Answer (score 4):

To use a categorical variable as input you can encode it as a set of boolean inputs, each representing one category with 0 or 1. For instance, your 'purpose' variable can be transformed into three boolean variables (furniture, education, cars).

You can generate columns with category flags automatically like this:

```
flags = data.frame(Reduce(cbind, 
     lapply(levels(d$purpose), function(x){(d$purpose == x)*1})
))
names(flags) = levels(d$purpose)
d = cbind(d, flags)

# Include the new columns as input variables
levelnames = paste(names(flags), collapse = " + ")
neuralnet(paste("output ~ ", levelnames), d)
```

Comment: Thanks user3324985. Can I do this for all of my variables which I want to convert into boolean inputs?

 flags = data.frame(Reduce(cbind, 
 lapply(levels(d[2:10), function(x){(d[2:10 == x)*1})
 ))