# Converting Categorical Columns into Multiple Binary Columns in R

Tags: r

I am trying to convert a column that has categorical data ('A', 'B', or 'C') to 3 columns where 1,0,0 would be 'A'; 0,1,0 would represent 'B', etc.

I found this code online:

```
flags = data.frame(Reduce(cbind, 
     lapply(levels(d$purpose), function(x){(d$purpose == x)*1})
))
names(flags) = levels(d$purpose)
d = cbind(d, flags)

# Include the new columns as input variables
levelnames = paste(names(flags), collapse = " + ")
neuralnet(paste("output ~ ", levelnames), d)
```

[Converting categorical variables in R for ANN (neuralnet)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27183827/converting-categorical-variables-in-r-for-ann-neuralnet)

But I'm very new to R. Can anyone break down what this complicated looking code is doing?

edit:

Implementing @nongkrong's recommendations I'm running into a problem:

CSV:

```
X1,X2,X3
A,D,Q
B,E,R
C,F,S
B,G,T
C,H,U
A,D,Q
```

R:

```
newData <- read.csv("new.csv")
newerData <- model.matrix(~ X1 + X2 + X3 -1, data=newData)
newerData
```

R Output:

```
  X1A X1B X1C X2E X2F X2G X2H X3R X3S X3T X3U
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
3   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0
4   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0
5   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1
6   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

It works great with 1 column, but is missing X2D and X3Q.  Any ideas why?

Comment: i don't think this code is necessary, you can use simply `model.matrix(~ purpose -1, data=d)`, but all it is doing is expanding the factor variable into a bunch of dummy columns.  Each dummy column corresponds to a level of the original factor, and is 1 where that factor was present in the original

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  I got this to work great with 1 column but am getting odd results with multiple columns (see my edit of op)

Comment: I guess it's because of `-1`, try removing that and see what you get (though I would have expected `X1A` to be dropped as well...)

Comment: It removed an Intercept column.  I got around it for now by doing 1 column at a time and using cbind to combine them

Comment: the output is like that because these dummy columns are contrasting different combinations of your factors against a base case, the intercept (which was removed from the model by using `-1`).  I'm not sure how to include those columns as dummies as well, sadly

Answer (score 2):

@nongkrong is right--read `?formulas` and you'll see that most functions that accept `formula`s as input (e.g. `lm`, `glm`, etc.) will automatically convert categorical variables (stored as `factor`s or `character`s) to dummies; you can force this on non-`factor` numeric variables by specifying `as.factor(var)` in your formula.

That said, I've encountered situations where it's convenient to have created these indicators by hand anyway--e.g., a data set with an ethnicity variable where <1% of the data fit in one or several of the ethnicity codes. There are other ways to deal with this (simply delete the minority-minority observations, e.g.), but I find that varies by situation.

So, I've annotated the code for you:

```
flags = data.frame(Reduce(cbind, 
     lapply(levels(d$purpose), function(x){(d$purpose == x)*1})
))
```

Lots going on in this first line, so let's go bit-by-bit:

`d$purpose==x` checks each entry of `d$purpose` for equality to `x`; the result will be `TRUE` or `FALSE` (or `NA` if there are missing values). Multiplying by `1` (`*1`) forces the output to be an integer (so `TRUE` becomes `1` and `FALSE` becomes `0`).

`lapply` applies the function in its second argument to each element of its first argument--so for each element of `levels(d$purpose)` (i.e., each level of `d$purpose`), we output a vector of `0`s and `1`s, where the `1`s correspond to the elements of `d$purpose` matching the given level. The output of `lapply` is a `list` (hence `l` in front of apply), with one list element corresponding to each of the levels of `d$purpose`.

We want to get this into our `data.frame`, so a `list` isn't very useful; `Reduce` is what we use to back out the information from the `list` to a `data.frame` form. `Reduce(cbind,LIST)` is the same as `cbind(LIST[[1]],LIST[[2]],LIST[[3]],...)`--convenient shorthand, especially when we don't know the length of `LIST`.

Wrapping this in `data.frame` casts this into the mode `data.frame`.

```
#This line simply puts column names on each of the indicator variables
#  Note that you can replace the RHS of this line with whatever 
#  naming convention you want for the levels--a common approach might
#  be to specify paste0(levels(d$purpose),"_flag"), e.g.
names(flags) = levels(d$purpose)
#this line adds all the indicator variables to the original 
#  data.frame
d = cbind(d, flags)
#this creates a string of the form "level1 + level2 + ... + leveln"
levelnames = paste(names(flags), collapse = " + ")
#finally we create a formula of the form y~x+d1+d2+d3
#  where each of the d* is a dummy for a level of the categorical variable
neuralnet(paste("output ~ ", levelnames), d)
```

---

Also note that something like this could have been done much simpler in the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d)
l = levels(purpose)
d[ , (l) := lapply(l, function(x) as.integer(purpose == x))]
d[ , neuralnet(paste0("output~", paste0(l, collapse = "+"))]
```

Comment: @Michael.How to write if suppose i have multiple columns with multiple factors in each column.Can i repeat the Code for each column ?

Comment: I write the following Code but it's not working,dummy data .
`df <- structure(list(x1 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), 
    x2 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("x", "y", "z"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("x1", 
"x2"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: `fact1 <- c('x1','x2');
for(i in seq_along(1:2)){
   print( lapply(lapply(df[fact1],
                              function(x) levels(x))[[i]],
                       function(x){df[fact1][[i]]== x}*1))
  
} `

Comment: @user7462639 i recommend asking a new question, making sure to cite this question and include your attempts thus far. as i recommended in my answer, you probably don't want to do this yourself; see also the `model.matrix` function